# ffmpegthumbnailer not generating thumbnails of size 600

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, ffmpegthumbnailer

I got an issue with ffmpegthumbnailer, used following command to generate thumbnails from  new.mp4.

```
ffmpegthumbnailer -i new.mp4 -o tmpfile1.jpg -c jpg -q 10 -s 600
```

Got following error and failed to generate thumbnail.

```
Not a native file, thumbnailing will likely fail
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to create another version using same command except size attribute( -s 640 instead of -s 600).

```
ffmpegthumbnailer -i new.mp4 -o tmpfile1.jpg -c jpg -q 10 -s 640
```

thumbnail successfully generated.

I don't know why thumbnail of version-600 not getting generated.